# How to extract null value from QLineEdit; if user fails to fill the QLineEdit field

Tags: python, sqlite, null, pyqt5, qlineedit

I am creating a form that gets all the user information and upon clicking save button all the details will be stored in sqlite3 dB.

I have created the table in sqlite3 dB with NOT NULL constraint applied for all the columns. But still if user fails to fill details for any of the QLineEdit , columns in the DB are updated with blank value.

But I am looking for Null constrain error if user fails to fill the QLineEdit.Please help me out.I am using pyqt5 for python.

Comment: I am trying to get the data from user through Lineedit and saving it to a table in Sqlite3. But when user does not enter any value empty string gets stored in the table. but I am looking for Null value exception when user fails to fill the value in the Lineedit

Comment: I want to analyze where the problem is, so I asked you to provide an MCVE, can you do it?